# Google Maps Color B&W

Tags: maps

Can I use this code in the an iframe for a wordpress page post to make my map black and white? I would like a map just like this: http://wegrowcherries.com/about/

```
[ { 
"featureType": "water", 
"stylers": [ { 
"color": "#ffffff" } 
] },

{ 
"featureType": "landscape", 
"elementType": "geometry", 
"stylers": [ { 
"color": "#000000" } 
 ] },

{ 
"featureType": "administrative", 
"elementType": "labels.text.fill", 
"stylers": [ { 
"color": "#ffffff" } 
] },

{ 
"featureType": "administrative", 
"elementType": "labels.text.stroke", 
"stylers": [ { 
"visibility": "simplified" } 
] },

{ 
"featureType": "road", 
"elementType": "geometry", 
"stylers": [ { 
"visibility": "off" } 
] },

{ 
"featureType": "poi", 
"elementType": "geometry.fill", 
"stylers": [ { 
"color": "#000000" }, { 
"visibility": "simplified" } 
]},

{ 
"featureType": "administrative.province", 
"stylers": [ { 
"visibility": "off" } 
]},

{ 
"featureType": "road", 
"elementType": "geometry.stroke", 
"stylers": [ { 
"color": "#ffffff" }, { 
"weight": 2 }, { 
"visibility": "off" } 
]},

{ 
"featureType": "administrative.locality", 
"stylers": [ { "visibility": "off" } 
]},

{ 
"featureType": "road", 
"elementType": "labels", 
"stylers": [ { 
"visibility": "off" } 
] },

{ 
"featureType": "poi", 
"stylers": [ { 
"visibility": "off" } 
] },

{ 
"featureType": "transit", 
"stylers": [ { 
"visibility": "off" } 
]},

{ 
"featureType": "administrative.neighborhood", 
"stylers": [ { 
"visibility": "off" } 
] }]
```

iframe code in wordpress blog. Can I paste the above in here with a style="" tag?

```
<iframe style="border: 0; width: 100%" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d4046390.158269976!2d114.49410816221383!3d-7.941674640018978!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x2dd141d3e8100fa1%3A0x24910fb14b24e690!2sBali%2C+Indonesia!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1390525274478" height="250" width="900" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct (and [legal](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) ) way to do this is using the  use their [Styled Maps Api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling)

It looks like the code above is using that API. As detailed in the Styled Maps API page, you have to create a StyledMapType (like your code above) and pass it to the constructor in your javascript.

#### Creating a StyledMapType

> You can create a new map type to which to apply styles, by creating a
> StyledMapType and passing the feature and styler information to the
> constructor. This approach does not affect the style of the default
> map types.

Comment: So I can't just add the code into an iframe? Does javascript work in a wordpress text post?

Comment: Yes, you can get javascript working in a wordpress post. Just include it in the post template header.

Comment: How do I include it in the post template header?

Comment: You include it in `header.php`. See the section titled "JavaScript in Posts" in this page: => http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript It looks like if you are creating just a 1 off post, you don't need to include it in the theme's `header.php`. Instead you can include it inside the body of the Post as detailed in the aforementioned link. The link details both approaches. HTH.